# Cleanest way to set createdAt timestamp / datetime in object

Tags: php, symfony, class, doctrine

I've had this issue already a few times, I'm never sure the best / cleanest way to handle it. I want to create a `createdAt` (timestamp / datetime) field in a Symfony class / object. I know there's several ways to handle it, but I wanted to ask whether perhaps there is a "cleanest" way to do it.

**Option 1: Create in constructor** (current favorite)

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
}
```

I like this the most, because it is explicit and it is set during "construction".

A connected question would be, if I get an entity out of the database via a repository, will the constructor ever be called (i.e. `new \DateTime()` is called to be overwritten with the database value directly after)?

**Option 2: Default value in class**

```
class MyClass {

    protected $createdAt = new \DateTime();

    /** ... */
}
```

This is fine, I suppose?

**Option 3: Lifecycle callback**

```
/**
 * @PrePersist
 */
public function onPrePersistCreated()
{
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
}
```

I find it a bit unelegant, because it's somewhat of a side-effect, but perhaps ok. Another drawback is that I have to wait for it to be persisted to database for me to get the `createdAt`.

Similar would be to use DoctrineExtensions' `Timestampable`.

**Option 4: Default value in Database**

In the Symfony class Doctrine annotation you can set default value for `$createdAt`, but I find this a bit unstable. Something like

```
/**
* @var \DateTime
* @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", options={"default" : "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
*/
```

(didn't test the code, perhaps `"NOW()"` needed?) But this is even more reliant on the database.

So my question is, which is the cleanest way or does it depend on the case?

Comment: You can throw away Option 2. Expression is not allowed as property default value. Property initialization, must be a constant value - that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for StackOverflow, maybe better for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? Even then, there is no proper answer, only opinions. Just as "cleanlyness" is an opinion. I would go for option 3 in an eventlistener (and not the entity), because I feel it separates concerns better

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 and 3 are valid, 2 is not possible and 4 its difficult to implement.

> if I get an entity out of the database via a repository, will the
>   constructor ever be called (i.e. new \DateTime() is called to be
>   overwritten with the database value directly after)?

The constructor is not called when the entity is fetched from database, doctrine use Proxy objects and override your constructor when the entity is loaded. Then the constructor in only called one time, when the entity is created the first time.